# Django login only using username and hash

Tags: python, django, hash

I want to implement software client which will interact with django server. I need users loging in on client.

1. Is it possible check user is in database and its password, only with username and it's password ? Something like:

   ```
   if user_valid(username, password):
       do something;
   ```
2. I don't want to send open password, is it possible to send only it's hash? How can I obtain valid hash? The auth method in this case shoud be:

   ```
   if user_valid(username, password_hash):
       do something;
   ```

Comment: have you considered using SSL?

Comment: Better create a REST API and consume it from your client application: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Thanks! But I thougt it shoud be easy without any external modules: the only thing I need is get user object from database by username and compare his hash with received hash (if it is possible?). But I need to know how to obtain the hash on client side. Other security issues is not interesting for me becouse all communication between client and server will be performed via RSA encrypted messages, so if client will enter uncorrect password, he will not receive public key, and will not able to send correct messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/jpulgarin/django-tokenapi

Basically you'll need to generate a token based on the user .. in the example below, the author is using user primarykey and  password.

Example:

> https://github.com/jpulgarin/django-tokenapi/blob/master/tokenapi/tokens.py#L15

Following that.. you can implement a custom authentication backend .. which will allow user to login using the generated token.

Example:

> https://github.com/jpulgarin/django-tokenapi/blob/master/tokenapi/backends.py#L13

More information on custom authentication backend

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#customizing-authentication-in-django